# why wont this unity animation work

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hey guys I'm having trouble with this code. I've been working on it a while and can't seem to figure it out. What am i doing wrong?(I'm only having trouble on the animation bit.)

```
    #pragma strict
    public var clip : AnimationClip;
    public var riffle : Sprite;
    public var pistol : Sprite;
    function Start () {
     }
    function Anima(){
        GetComponent.<Animation>().Play(GetComponent.<Animation>().clip.name);
     }
    function Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("a")){
            print("A");
            GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = riffle;
     }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("d")){
            print("D");
            GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = pistol;
    }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("w")){
            Anima();
     }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("s")){
            Anima();
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a NullReferenceException on the line inside of the anima() function. I'm not exactly sure what that means either.

Comment: Use CrossFade it work for me : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.CrossFade.html

Comment: Are you sure `GetComponent.<Animation>()` is returning something?

Answer (score 0):

> NullReferenceException on the line inside of the anima() function

it clearly means that where the script has attached doesn't have an Animation Component. Please make sure where you have attached this script must have animation component.